# Convert string to ReadableStream in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, browser, stream

How to convert a string to [ReadableStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream) (not NodeJS stream).

Answer (score -1):

To convert a string to ReadableStream

```js
function stringToStream(str) {
    return new ReadableStream({
        start(controller) { // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStreamDefaultController
            controller.enqueue(str); 
            controller.close();
        },
    })
}
const stringStream = stringToStream("some text");
// convert the string stream to byte using TextEncoderStream if you need to consume as byte like .pipeThrough(new CompressionStream())
const byteStream = stringStream.pipeThrough(new TextEncoderStream())
```

Or oneline solution by [`Blob.stream()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/stream)

```js
const byteStream = new Blob([ str ], {type: 'text/plain'}).stream();
```